# Function excel for split a cell, vlookup into a column and concatena

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've one range with the value in column 1 and I want to look for the cells in Column 2 if they are in the range of col 1. When they are in the range I want the function to give me the value is col 2 belonging to the range of col 1.
I've done it with excel by doing a text to column, then a vlookup and after I concatenate the value, but I would like to make it with a function.

Example:

```
Col A            Col B              Col C(result)
1                1, 4, 8                  1, 4
4 
5 
6 
10
```

If someone as an idea, any help would be appreciate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following UDF (**U**ser **D**efined **F**unction):

```
Public Function SubString(rng As Range, sIN As String) As String
    Dim sep As String, temp As String
    Dim r As Range
    SubString = ""
    sep = ", "
    If sIN = "" Then Exit Function
    If InStr(sIN, sep) = 0 Then Exit Function

    ary = Split(sIN, sep)
    For Each a In ary
        For Each r In rng
            If a = r.Text Then
                temp = temp & a & sep
                Exit For
            End If
        Next r
    Next a
    SubString = Mid(temp, 1, Len(temp) - 2)
End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=SubString(A1:A5,B1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**